# Expanding Big Query table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables:

```
-- +---------+
-- | Title   |
-- +---------+
-- | Title 1 |
-- | Title 2 | 
-- | Title 3 |
-- | Title 4 |
-- +---------+
```

And:

```
-- +---------+
-- | Name    |
-- +---------+
-- | Name  1 |
-- | Name  2 | 
-- | Name  3 |
-- +---------+
```

Is there a SQL statement in Big Query that helps me duplicate the rows using names from second column? Desired result should look like this. SO basically I want to duplicate first table using distinct values in second one.

```
-- +---------+---------+
-- | Title   | Name    |
-- +---------+---------+
-- | Title 1 | Name  1 |
-- | Title 2 | Name  1 | 
-- | Title 3 | Name  1 | 
-- | Title 4 | Name  1 | 
-- | Title 1 | Name  2 | 
-- | Title 2 | Name  2 | 
-- | Title 3 | Name  2 |
-- | Title 4 | Name  2 |
-- | Title 1 | Name  3 |
-- | Title 2 | Name  3 |
-- | Title 3 | Name  3 |
-- | Title 4 | Name  3 |
-- +---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `cross join`:

```
select t1.title, t2.name
from t1 cross join
     t2;
```